# How to change the style of a text to a particular pattern using regex?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a textarea like what is in stackoverflow's ask-page. Now I want to replace some text to some specific pattern. In other word I want to add some tags around a text. I want something like these:

```
**bold**
__underline__
*italics*
--strike--
[linkname](www.example.com)
```

Well, I'm newbie to PHP... But I did it using javascript:

```
text.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
text.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<u>$1</u>");
text.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<i>$1</i>");
text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, "<del>$1</del>");

// also I didn't know do that for link-href
// I want this: <a href="www.example.com">linkname</a>
```

So, how can I do that using php? (I want to check the content both client-side and server-side, Because maybe javacript is deactivate on some of visitor's system)

Comment: Use almost the same regexps with `preg_replace` function. `g` global flag must be removed.

Comment: @stribizhev oh really?! good. But what is your opinion about link-method?

Comment: Maybe [`\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/hG6kX1/1)?

Comment: @stribizhev tnx, it could be better https://regex101.com/r/hG6kX1/2

Comment: Why don't you use a library for this? I guarantee it will be easier on you. https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php#L1171

Comment: @miken32 actually I don't know how should I use that...! You linked me a line of a large number of codes ..! Well, I'm newbie to php. Please give me some more explanation about how should I use it ... . Beforehand thank you.

Comment: Then you certainly shouldn't be trying to do this. Use a library! http://parsedown.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP there is a function called [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), this is the one you are searching for.

For your second problem with the link, you could do something like this, this makes a simple check, to be sure that the URL is valid. 
`(?:^\[)(.*?)(?:\]\()(www\..+?\.\D+?)(?:\))`

UPDATE 1:
Simple use with my regex as requested:
    `<?php
    $string = '[linkname](www.example.com)';
    $pattern = '/(?:^\[)(.*?)(?:\]\()(www\..+?\.\D+?)(?:\))/';
    $replacement = '${1}, $2';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);`

For doing all of this easier you can use this PHP class: (Suggested by @miken32): 
https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php#L1171

Comment: Can you use your regex in `preg-replace` function?

Comment: Just updated the regex, so it needs to have at least 1 character in TLD and domainname, but the linkname can be empty. So now you can better catch correct domainnames.